# Error in Serializing NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

Im attempting to serialize an NSDictionary and and getting the following error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

This is a small portion Object I'm attempting to serialize. Its the same format throughout, I have just removed most of the items.

```
{
    action = Websites;
    method = "school_webpage";
    result =     {
        CurrentStatus = 1;
        Description = OK;
        ReturnValue =         {
            bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";
            splash = "";
            tree =             (
                                {
                    children =                     (
                                                {
                            iconCls = "icn-add";
                            id = 462793;
                            leaf = 1;
                            showAdd = 0;
                            text = "Ahrens, Linda";
                            type = website;
                        },
                                                {
                            iconCls = "icn-add";
                            id = 498858;
                            leaf = 1;
                            showAdd = 0;
                            text = "Altemose, David";
                            type = website;
                        },
                                                {
                            iconCls = "icn-add";
                            id = 11159347;
                            leaf = 1;
                            showAdd = 0;
                            text = "Alvin, Patrick";
                            type = website;
                        }
}
```

My code below. This NSDictionary is passed through as an AnyObject

```
func parseJson(_ JsonDict: AnyObject)
{
    print(JsonDict)
    var data = [newsarticle]()
    do{
        let jsonData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: JsonDict)
            let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData,       options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers )

            if let dict = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                if let dict2 = (dict as? [String : AnyObject])?["result"]?["ReturnValue"]{

                    if let dict3 = (dict2 as! [String: AnyObject])["tree"]  as? [AnyObject] {

                        for dict4  in dict3 {
                            if let dict5 = dict4["children"]  as? [AnyObject]{
                                for dict6 in dict5{
                                    data.append(newsarticle(name: ((dict6 as? [String : AnyObject])?["text"])! as! String,desc: "https://www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/\((dict6 as? [String : AnyObject])?["id"])/689493"))
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        addData(data)
                    }
                }


            }


        }

    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult to read.  I recommend you spend some time cleaning your code up, such as:

```
if let dict = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let dict2 = (dict as? [String : AnyObject])?["result"]?["ReturnValue"] {

    }
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
if let dict = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let returnValue = dict["result"]?["ReturnValue"] {

    }
}
```

Because you've already unwrapped `dict` as a `[String: AnyObject]` in the first line.  And use more descriptive variable names because `dict5` will not help you know where you're at in trying to parse things.

So have a look at this line, the `try` statement is what's causing your error.

```
let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers )
```

It's essentially saying, whatever you're passing in as `jsonData` is not real json.  I recommend you run whatever `jsonData` is through a site like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and fix up the format until it's valid.